# haproxy and sticky session

Tags: cookies, haproxy

I need to have sticky sessions on my haproxy(1.4). Below my backend configuration.

> ```
>     cookie SRVSTICKY insert indirect nocache
>       server server1 192.162.20.1:80 check cookie s1
>       server server2 192.162.20.2:80 check cookie s2
> ```

This works well but in the case where the client doesn't accept the cookies, the loading of my webpage doesn't works.
I've try to add a third server without cookie to redirect these clients(like a default server). But this doesn't works.

Have you got an idea, to redirect a client who blocks cookies session, to a default server?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who deal with cookie-incompatible clients generally use source address, because at least one of these two features works in general (eg: some payment terminals or webservice clients that do not support cookies will have a fixed address).

Comment: Thanks Willy, your answer is a good idea to solve my case. Just another question. Is it possible to share the stick table between haproxys? I don't find that in your documentation, I think she's stored locally(RAM?). And is it possible to keep the stick table reload's persistent ?

Comment: @Matt With HAProxy 1.5 (currently at dev14, thus beta) you can setup multiple instances to synchronize their stick tables. See [the documentation](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#3.5) for details.

Comment: Haproxy 1.5 will be a great version. So many features :) Thanks for your answers.